# Formatting a USB flash drive

Tags: encryption, usb-drive, disk-formatting

I have a simple question, but still need some advice before I continue, since I already ruined one USB flash drive once.

I am running a Ubuntu 20.04 system and have a USB flash drive of 128 GB. I want to format that USB flash drive and then create a single encrypted partition on it. When I insert the flash drive and open the Disk tool, this is what I see for that USB flash drive:

[image]

What is the use of the "Free Space" of 3.9 MB? Do I need it? Should I keep it?
There are also some files that came with the USB drive:

[image]

I think that those are useless form me (except perhaps the pdf file), since I don't have a Windows system. Should I care about those files and copy them somewhere?

I'm sure that those are quite stupid questions for most of you, but perhaps someone can provide me with some general explanation of what to do or not do in order not to ruin yet another flash drive.

Comment: Those are usually Windows or Mac applications.  If you feel you might need it in the future back it up to another location before formatting the drive.

Comment: 1. I don't know why there is "Free Space" of 3.9 MB at the head end of the drive. Classical partitioning leaves 1.0 MiB at the head end. I don't think you need it unless it is a special drive with some kind of built in encryption or other special feature. But that drive space is so small, so you might as well leave it; 2. I don't think you will need the three files. - If I had this USB drive, I would [install and] use `gparted`, create a fresh partition table and then the partition(s) and file system(s) that I want, in other words, I would overwrite everything that is on the drive now.